# Why does spark-shell throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when reading a large file from HDFS?

Tags: apache-spark

I am using hadoop 2.4.1 and Spark 1.1.0. I have uploaded a dataset of food review to HDFS from [here](https://snap.stanford.edu/data/web-FineFoods.html) and then I used the following code to read the file and process it on the spark shell:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job
import org.apache.hadoop.io.{LongWritable, Text}
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat

var path = "hdfs:///user/hduser/finefoods.txt"
val conf = new Configuration
conf.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter", "\n\n")
var dataset = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(path, classOf[TextInputFormat], classOf[LongWritable], classOf[Text], conf).map(_._2.toString)
var datasetObj = dataset.map{ rowStr => rowStr.split("\n")}    
var tupleSet = datasetObj.map( strArr => strArr.map( elm => elm.split(": ")(1))).map( arr => (arr(0),arr(1),arr(4).toDouble))
tupleSet.groupBy(t => t._2)
```

When I run the last line `tupleSet.groupBy(t => t._2)`, the spark shell throws the following exception:

```
scala> tupleSet.groupBy( t => t._2).first()
14/11/15 22:46:59 INFO spark.SparkContext: Starting job: first at <console>:28
14/11/15 22:46:59 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Registering RDD 11 (groupBy at <console>:28)
14/11/15 22:46:59 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Got job 1 (first at <console>:28) with 1 output partitions (allowLocal=true)
14/11/15 22:46:59 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Final stage: Stage 1(first at <console>:28)
14/11/15 22:46:59 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List(Stage 2)
14/11/15 22:46:59 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List(Stage 2)
14/11/15 22:46:59 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting Stage 2 (MappedRDD[11] at groupBy at <console>:28), which has no missing parents
14/11/15 22:46:59 INFO storage.MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(3592) called with curMem=221261, maxMem=278302556
14/11/15 22:46:59 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_2 stored as values in memory (estimated size 3.5 KB, free 265.2 MB)
14/11/15 22:46:59 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting 3 missing tasks from Stage 2 (MappedRDD[11] at groupBy at <console>:28)
14/11/15 22:46:59 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 2.0 with 3 tasks
14/11/15 22:46:59 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 3, localhost, ANY, 1221 bytes)
14/11/15 22:46:59 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 4, localhost, ANY, 1221 bytes)
14/11/15 22:46:59 INFO executor.Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 3)
14/11/15 22:46:59 INFO executor.Executor: Running task 1.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 4)
14/11/15 22:46:59 INFO rdd.NewHadoopRDD: Input split: hdfs://10.12.0.245/user/hduser/finefoods.txt:0+134217728
14/11/15 22:46:59 INFO rdd.NewHadoopRDD: Input split: hdfs://10.12.0.245/user/hduser/finefoods.txt:134217728+134217728
14/11/15 22:47:02 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 4)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
14/11/15 22:47:02 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 2.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 5, localhost, ANY, 1221 bytes)
14/11/15 22:47:02 INFO executor.Executor: Running task 2.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 5)
14/11/15 22:47:02 INFO rdd.NewHadoopRDD: Input split: hdfs://10.12.0.245/user/hduser/finefoods.txt:268435456+102361028
14/11/15 22:47:02 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 4, localhost): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

14/11/15 22:47:02 ERROR scheduler.TaskSetManager: Task 1 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
14/11/15 22:47:02 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 2
14/11/15 22:47:02 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Stage 2 was cancelled
14/11/15 22:47:02 INFO executor.Executor: Executor is trying to kill task 2.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 5)
14/11/15 22:47:02 INFO executor.Executor: Executor is trying to kill task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 3)
14/11/15 22:47:02 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Failed to run first at <console>:28
14/11/15 22:47:02 INFO executor.Executor: Executor killed task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 3)
14/11/15 22:47:02 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 3, localhost): TaskKilled (killed intentionally)
14/11/15 22:47:02 INFO executor.Executor: Executor killed task 2.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 5)
14/11/15 22:47:02 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 2.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 5, localhost): TaskKilled (killed intentionally)
14/11/15 22:47:02 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 2.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 4, localhost): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1185)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1174)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1173)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1173)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:688)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:688)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:688)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessActor$$anonfun$receive$2.applyOrElse(DAGScheduler.scala:1391)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:498)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:456)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:237)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

But when I use dummy dataset like the following, it works well:

```
var tupleSet = sc.parallelize(List(
("B001E4KFG0","A3SGXH7AUHU8GW",3.0),
("B001E4KFG1","A3SGXH7AUHU8GW",4.0),
("B001E4KFG2","A3SGXH7AUHU8GW",4.0),
("B001E4KFG3","A3SGXH7AUHU8GW",4.0),
("B001E4KFG4","A3SGXH7AUHU8GW",5.0),
("B001E4KFG5","A3SGXH7AUHU8GW",5.0),
("B001E4KFG0","bbb",5.0)
))
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's probably an entry in the dataset that does not follow the format and therefore: `elm.split(": ")(1)` fails, because there's no element at that index.

You can avoid that error by checking the results of the split before accessing the (1) index. One way of doing that could be something like this:

```
var tupleSet = datasetObj.map(elem => elm.split(": ")).collect{case x if (x.length>1) x(1)}
```

One note: Your examples do not seem to match the parsing pipeline in the code. They do not contain the ": " tokens.

Since the transformations are lazy Spark won't tell you much about your input dataset (and you may not notice it) only until executing an action like `groupBy()`.

Answer (score 0):

It could also be due to empty/blank lines in your dataset. And, you are applying a split function on the data. In such case, filter out the empty lines.

Eg: myrdd.filter(_.nonEmpty).map(...)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I was converting a log data into dataframe using pySpark.

When a log entry is invalid, I returned a null value instead of a Row instance. Before converting to dataframe, I filtered out these null values. But, still, I got the above problem. Finally, the error went away when I returned a Row with null values instead of a single null value.

Pseudo code below:

*Didnt work:*

```
rdd = Parse log (log lines to Rows if valid else None)
filtered_rdd = rdd.filter(lambda x:x!=None)
logs = sqlContext.inferSchema(filtered_rdd)
```

*Worked:*

```
rdd = Parse log (log lines to Rows if valid else Row(None,None,...))
logs = sqlContext.inferSchema(rdd)
filtered_rdd = logs.filter(logs['id'].isNotNull())
```